# Exploring fitsSystemWindows and transparent status bar in android

Tags: android

Kindly assume everything is only for target and minSDK vesion is lollipop only.

**What I want**

I am trying to implement an activity similar to the following screen from play store.

[image]

I am focusing on the Hero image here. As you see, 
1. hero image is drawn behind status bar. (Completely transparent. No protection)
2. Rest of the content is drawn below status bar. (Eg., Toolbar/ActionBar)
3. While scrolling the status bar is colored.

**What I have done**

I have used ScrimInsetsFrameLayout from GoogleIO app. Wrapped my hero image around this layout. Added proper styling in my theme. This is what I get

[image]

**Help I need**

1. I am still confused about fitsSystemWindows tag. When I set this to "true" on the hero image layout, nothing happens. That is status bar is transparent but image is drawn below status bar. If set to "false", I get the above result. Is there a clear article that explains the usage and behind the scenes of this tag.
2. I set the "insetForeground" on ScrimInsetFrameLayout to transparent. Also in the theme I set the status bar color as transparent. But still there is a protection over the image. How to make the status bar completely transparent.

Kindly help me with a pointers or demo projects. Also let me know if i am not clear or need more info.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.

layout.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout 
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/parallax_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and set `statusBarColor` attribute with transparent color at styles.xml v-21

Comment: How is this anywhere near having an image behind the status bar with no transparent scrim on top of it?

Comment: setting  android:fitsSystemWindows="true" in ImageVied fixed it for me, thank you

Comment: Add, For use fistystemwidows need before set in values21/styles.xml <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>

Answer (score -1):

Add the following line to the view where you don't want the toolbar to overlap:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```